Is their any predefined Model Avaiable in Vertex AI for cloud logging analysis?
I am required to analyze the GCP Cloud and Audit logs using AI models. We created a log sink and dumped all required logs in a BQ table. Now, which vertex AI model will be good for analyzing the logs and providing us with information? e.g., Information about the error, which service instance was created, etc.
I cant find a specific model which can help me in this, is there any or i have to write a custom model(please guide).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEm8eRNTVic ?
